# Sophisticated splitting of an string by semicolon

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to import the whole database which is actually a .sql file, and import it to mysql server. In this database I have a table, which stores html code.

I use `mysqli` to connect to the database, which works fine.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(mysql_host, mysql_username, mysql_password, mysql_database);
```

Next, I am getting the content out of the .sql file by using the function `file_get_contents()` and place it in the `$sql` var. I split the `$sql` on every semicolon. In doing so I have one single query.

```
$sql = file_get_contents(sql_filename);
$queries = preg_split("/(;|#|%%)/", $sql );
```

I use `$mysqli->query` which executes the query on on the database.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($queries)-1; $i++){
        //mysql_query($queries[$i]) or die(mysql_error());
        $result = $mysqli->query($queries[$i]);
        if (!$result) {
            die('<br>Invalid query: ' . $queries[$i]);
        } else {
            echo 'Query: '. $queries[$i] ." is successful... <br>";
        }
    }
```

This works fine:

```
drop database if exists databasename;
create database business_databasename;
use databasename;
```

I'm facing the problem that it splits on every semicolon.

```
INSERT INTO `mtgpV1_template` (`id`, `name`, `content`) VALUES
(1, 'Sjabloon 1', '<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>...
<style type="text/css">\r\n<!--\r\nbody,td,th {
    \r\n    font-family: verdana;\r\n   font-size: 10px;\r\n
```

I want to prevent the split to happen if the semicolon is inside a . How can i make this happen?

Or if its possible is there another way of importing a .sql file and performing multiple queries by using php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = file_get_contents(sql_filename);
$mysqli->multy_query($sql);
```